# Visual Studio Partitioned Solution Build Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, solution

I am building out the structure of a large project in Visual Studio 2012 using the Partitioned Single Solution model described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx). I have an MVC 4 project targeting .Net 4.5, a business logic/data access tier, and a common solution with some shared code (loggers and the like). When I build my (completely empty, right out of the box) MVC solution it builds just fine, but when I build my Master solution I get an error stating that the TableAttribute exists both in the Entity Framework assembly and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations:

```
The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute' exists in both 'c:\Users\cori\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DNR\Web\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'
```

I have examined both references in both solutions (the MVC-only one and the Master solution that contains the MVC projects) and they refer to the same files at the locations referenced in the error message in both projects, yet I do not get the error in the MVC solution.

I'm guessing that there's some under-the-hood configuration that takes care of the conflict in the MVC project but not in the Master project (which I created by using the New Project from Existing Code option). If that's the case, what configuration am I missing?

Comment: This is really difficult to tell, but I suspect it's in the web.config file. You could just copy the web.config from your MVC Project to the Master one, and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ChristopherStevenson, but there is no web.config file in the Master project itself - only in the MVC-only project inside it (which is, of course, the same one that's in the MVC-only project). The master solution is essentially just a wrapper that includes all of the projects from its subsidiary solutions so the whole system can be built easily.

Comment: There's a terminology mis-communication: do you have a Master project within your solution?

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson yes, there *is* a technology verbiage problem, but it's all on my end - instead of adding the projects to the Master solution I had added the *folders* of the existing projects to the Master project within the Master solution. Once I got rid of the Master project and added the existing projects to the Master solution, everything's working great. Thanks!